# What is the difference between bún tươi and bún khô?

Tags: noodles, vietnamese-cuisine

There are two versions of Vietnamese rice noodles available. I'd like to know what is the difference, if any. They seem almost identical.

- [bún khô](http://s1347.photobucket.com/user/minh2610/media/1150309_420378471405548_417070255_n_zps1fac5610.jpg.html)
- [bún tươi](http://cat360.vn/datafiles/setone/14453345974718_bun-tuoi-safoco-300g.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that there doesn't seem to be a difference in the two. They are both rice vermicelli noodles.

While I found very few search results in English, they appear to be the same. I also searched images and found that there are packages of each but there are also packages labeled like this:

[image]

So I came away thinking it's more semantics than anything.

Answer (score 1):

@Cindy is correct, that both are made of rice flour. Similar to pasta, the difference is that one, bún tươi (fresh noodle), has just been made and cooked, and that bún khô (dry noodle) has been dried, as in the packaged product in the image.

Comment: Just FYI, I found both dried and in packages.

Comment: @Cindy :-) go figure ... would that be freshly dried ?

Comment: @Cindy at my Vietnamese market, I buy bún tươi which is flexible and the packaging is somewhat shrink wrapped. If the answer is incorrect, I'll delete to keep SE clean.

Comment: Same here. I don't doubt what you're saying. I'm just wondering, based on what I was able to find out, if the terms are sometimes used interchangeably.